# Continue loop after a function has finished executing. How to use jquery deffered

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each, jquery-deferred

I have the following data

```
var data = [{user:"somename"}, {user:"anothername"}];
```

I have this function that processes that that, let say checking user if it exist

```
function process(user) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://domain.com/api',
        success: function(result) {
            if(result == 'success')
                anotherFunction();
            else 
                console.log('error');
        }
    })
}

function anotherFunction() {
     $.ajax({

        // do stuffs
     })
}
```

$.each(data, function(k,v){
    process(v.user);
})

The `$.each` will try to loop even the `process` and the `anotherFunction` hasn't finished yet

Question, what can I do to assure that all functions are finished executing before moving on to another index?

I heard I can use jquery deferred.

Comment: so what's your actual question?

Comment: okay. I'll clear things. out. my question is how to continue loop after all the processes has finished executing..

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito It's still unclear what you want. Do you want `process()` to return after everything is done instead of at once?

Comment: I'll update the question., all.

Answer (score 1):

Collect the promises returned by your AJAX function, if necessary post-processing that result with `.then` so that it calls `anotherFunction()` *which must also `return` the result of `$.ajax`*.

```
function process() {
    return $.ajax(...).then(function(result) {
        if (result === 'success') {
             return anotherFunction();
        } else {
             return null;  // this might need to change...
        }
    });
}

function anotherFunction() {
    return $.ajax(...);
}

var promises = [];
$.each(data, function(k, v) {
    promises.push(process(v.data));
}
```

and then wait for all the promises to be resolved:

```
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
      // all done here
});
```

NB: in *general* it's good practise for an AJAX call to produce a non `2xx` return code for errors, rather than an error code within a "successful" HTTP call.  This then allows the client side code to use normal AJAX error processing (i.e. `.fail` callbacks) instead of checking for "errors" within AJAX success processing.

Comment: In principle what Alnitak says is correct but in this question (as originally given), there's all sorts of chained/recursive ajax going on, therefore `process()` needs to be constructed to return a promise of a *final outcome*, produced by a rather tricky `.then()` chain. No time to write it now ....

Comment: Alnitak, good call, though things get a bit messy if the code in the originally phrased (unsimplified) question is to be addressed.

Comment: can i use this? `$.get('http://domain.com/hey.tpl').then(function(result){
     // do stuffs.
    });`

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito yes, that's legal.  You should always try to `return` the result of `$.get`, though.